# Using a comment for file description and in mainpage

Tags: c++, doxygen

When I put in a given doxygen comment the command **\file**, it appears in the file description.

Wen I put the command **\mainpage** , it appears in the index.html page

If I put both, doxygen only considers the last one used. How can I put the same comment both in the file description and in the main page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the way doxygen works there is no way to have the same lines of comment be in *both* the file description and the main page. As the poster states if it is directly under `\file` it goes in the file description; if it is under `\mainpage` it goes in the main page.

If you want the same text to appear in multiple places it has to be copied, which is possible using e.g. the [`\copydoc` command](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#copydoc). `/** \mainpage \copydoc myfile.cpp */` would copy the `\file` comment from `myfile.cpp` to the main page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. that's exactly what I was looking for. I am a new user so I can't upvote. But I will do it asap :) But are you sure it is possible to achieve this with a custom command? it seems you can only define aliases...

Comment: I guess if the text is really long you would rather go with the  [`\copydoc` command](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html#copydoc).

Comment: This solution is definitely better because now i don t need to add a custom command (which I even doupt can work). All I have to do is to add under the file doc  
/*! \mainpage  
@copydoc myfile.cpp  
*/ with the back to line inside comments.

Comment: I suggest you update your solution in case someone else needs it later. thanks again

Comment: Even if you are a new user, you can accept the answer if it solves your problem (and so close the issue too).

Answer (score 0):

Look that example of [`mainpage`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdmainpage) command.

Comment: I read it before I asked. I am afraid you didn't understand my question.